# How to use findTransformEcc and warpAffine on resized image

Tags: opencv, text-alignment

I'm trying to align two images with `findTransfomECC` and `warpAffine`.

Here is my first attempt which is working fine:

```
    cv::Mat m = cv::Mat::eye(2, 3, CV_32F);
    auto criteria = cv::TermCriteria(
            cv::TermCriteria::COUNT + cv::TermCriteria::EPS, 50, 1e-5);
    cv::findTransformECC(prev_image, new_image, m, cv::MOTION_AFFINE, criteria, cv::noArray(), 5);
    cv::warpAffine(new_image, new_image, m, new_image.size(),
            cv::INTER_CUBIC + cv::WARP_INVERSE_MAP, cv::BORDER_CONSTANT, cv::Scalar::all(255));
```

The only problem is that it takes too much to calculate the warp matrix(m).

To redeam that, I tried to perform the `findTransformEcc` on the resized image and perform `warpAffine` on the original image. Here is the code:

```
    cv::Mat _new_image, _prev_image;
    cv::resize(new_image, _new_image, cv::Size(256,256), cv::INTER_AREA);
    cv::resize(prev_image_, _prev_image, cv::Size(256,256), cv::INTER_AREA);

    cv::Mat m = cv::Mat::eye(2, 3, CV_32F);
    auto criteria = cv::TermCriteria( 
            cv::TermCriteria::COUNT + cv::TermCriteria::EPS, 50, 1e-5);
    cv::findTransformECC(_prev_image, _new_image, m, cv::MOTION_AFFINE, criteria,
            cv::noArray(), 5);

    cv::warpAffine(new_image, _new_image, m, _new_image.size(),
            cv::INTER_CUBIC + cv::WARP_INVERSE_MAP, cv::BORDER_CONSTANT, cv::Scalar::all(255));
    //cv::resize(_new_image, new_image, new_image.size());
```

with this code, the `new_image` won't align to the `pre_image`.
I also tried to do `warpAffine` to the resized image and then resize the result to the original size.  But in this way the quality decreases.

Is there any way to perform `findTransfomeECC` on the resized(smaller) image instead of the original image?

Answer (score 0):

I come up with this solution:

```
    cv::Mat _new_image, _prev_image;
    cv::resize(new_image, new_image, cv::Size(256,256), cv::INTER_AREA);
    cv::resize(prev_image, _prev_image, cv::Size(256,256), cv::INTER_AREA);

    cv::Mat m = cv::Mat::eye(2, 3, CV_32F);

    auto criteria = cv::TermCriteria(cv::TermCriteria::COUNT + cv::TermCriteria::EPS, 50, 1e-5);
    cv::findTransformECC(prev_image, _new_image, m, cv::MOTION_AFFINE, criteria, cv::noArray(), 5);

    float h = _extracted_image.rows;
    float w = _extracted_image.cols;

    std::vector<cv::Point2f> _new_corners;
    std::vector<cv::Point2f> _old_corners = {
        cv::Point2f(0, 0),
        cv::Point2f(0, h),
        cv::Point2f(w, h),
        cv::Point2f(w, 0),
    };

    cv::transform(_old_corners, _new_corners, m);

    h = new_image.rows;
    w = new_image.cols;

    for (auto &c : _new_corners) {
        c.x = (c.x / 256) * w;
        c.y = (c.y / 256) * h;    
    }

    for (auto &c : _old_corners) {
        c.x = (c.x / 256) * w;
        c.y = (c.y / 256) * h;
    }

    cv::Mat M = cv::getPerspectiveTransform(_old_corners, _new_corners);

    cv::warpPerspective(new_image, new_image, M, new_image.size(),
        cv::INTER_CUBIC + cv::WARP_INVERSE_MAP , cv::BORDER_CONSTANT, cv::Scalar::all(255));
```

Here is some explanation:

1. apply `findTransformECC` on the resized image(256X256) and get the warp matrix.
2. define old corners as for corners of the resized image(256X256).
3. use `transform` to apply the warp matrix on old corners to get new corners of the resized image.
4. scale both old and new corners to the original image size.
5. use `getPerspectiveTransform` to find the perspective transformation matrix for the original image.
6. use `warpPerspective` to apply the perspective transformation matrix to the original image.